# reading a text file with unusual separator to panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
Hypothesis:

drink

Reference:

Drake
WER:

100.0

Time:

2.416645050048828

"---------------------------"

Hypothesis:

Ed Sheeran

Reference:

Ed Sheeran

WER:

0.0

Time:

2.854194164276123
```

When I try to read it as a panda.DataFrame with having `["Hypothesis", "Reference","WER","Time"]` as the columns, it returns an error.

I've tried:

```
txt= pd.read_csv("/home/kolagaza/Desktop/IAIS_en.txt", sep="---------------------------", header = None, engine='python')

data.columns = ["Hypothesis", "Reference","WER","Time"]
```

Comment: You are trying to access `data` without declaration.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the txt and data variation was just a typo here, but the error is regarding the separator sep="---------------------------"

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you would be able to read that text file directly into a pandas `DataFrame` without some preprocessing first. One way would be to transform your input into pandas `records` format, i.e. a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[{'Hypothesis': 'drink', 'Reference': 'Drake', 'WER': '100.0', 'Time': '2.416645050048828'},
 {'Hypothesis': 'Ed Sheeran','Reference': 'Ed Sheeran', 'WER': '0.0', 'Time': '2.854194164276123'}]
```

I tried the following code and it works for me (I copied your example text file):

```
import pandas as pd

records = []
with open ("/home/kolagaza/Desktop/IAIS_en.txt", "r") as fh:
    # remove blank lines and whitespaces
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fh.readlines() if line != "\n"]
    # this next line creates a list where each element will represent one line in the final dataframe
    lines = ",".join(lines).replace(':,', ':').split('"---------------------------"')
    # now convert each line into a record
    for line in lines:
        record = {}
        for keyval in line.split(','):
            if len(keyval) > 0:
                key, val = keyval.split(':')
                record[key] = val
        records.append(record)

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it sends an error:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)